# Image postprocessing for CMS

Tags: php, image-processing

Does anybody know a good PHP library for basic image postprocessing functions like hue / lightness / contrast using pure GD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually its a thumb library but it offers a lot of options for filter: [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) (Look here for some [demos](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php)).

Answer (score 2):

phpclasses.org has quit some libraries if i can remember.